# Conflicting lifetime requirements when storing closure capturing returned value

Tags: closures, rust

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to create a vector of closures inside a function, add a standard closure to the vector, and then return the vector from the function. I'm getting an error about conflicting lifetimes.

Code can be executed [here](http://is.gd/M07mm3).

```
fn vec_with_closure<'a, T>(f: Box<FnMut(T) + 'a>) -> Vec<Box<FnMut(T) + 'a>>
{
    let mut v = Vec::<Box<FnMut(T)>>::new();
    v.push(Box::new(|&mut: t: T| {
        f(t);
    }));
    v
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec_with_closure(Box::new(|t: usize| {
        println!("{}", t);
    }));
    for c in v.iter_mut() {
        c(10);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Using `Rc<RefCell<...>>` together with `move ||` and the `Fn()` trait as opposed to the `FnMut()`m as suggested by Shepmaster, helped me produce a working version of the above code. Rust playpen version [here](http://is.gd/oQyl5B).

Comment: I'd highly recommend creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us help you better. My guess is that you could remove many of the struct's methods and still reproduce the same problem.

Comment: I'll try to figure out a shorter version. Thanks.

Comment: Although some cursory poking at it seems to indicate that I could be wrong ;-). I think you can remove `T` and `'a` (replacing it with `'static`) to make it a tiny bit smaller.

Comment: Doesn't making it static push it to the global scope? I'm not sure I've entirely understood that lifetime yet. Need to read up, I guess. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my understanding of the problem, slightly slimmed down:

```
fn filter<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Keeper
    where F: Fn() -> bool + 'static //'
{
    let mut k = Keeper::new();
    self.subscribe(|| {
        if f() { k.publish() }
    });
    k
}
```

In this method, `f` is a value that has been passed in by-value, which means that `filter` owns it. Then, we create another closure that captures `f` *by-reference*. We are then trying to save that closure somewhere, so all the references in the closure need to outlive the lifetime of our struct (I picked `'static` for convenience).

However, `f` only lives until the end of the method, so it definitely won't live long enough. We need to make the closure own `f`. It would be ideal if we could use the `move` keyword, but that causes the closure to also move in `k`, so we wouldn't be able to return it from the function.

Trying to solve that led to this version:

```
fn filter<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Keeper
    where F: Fn() -> bool + 'static //'
{
    let mut k = Keeper::new();
    let k2 = &mut k;
    self.subscribe(move || {
        if f() { k2.publish() }
    });
    k
}
```

which has a useful error message:

```
error: `k` does not live long enough
let k2 = &mut k;
              ^
note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
...but borrowed value is only valid for the block
```

Which leads to another problem: you are trying to keep a reference to `k` in the closure, but that reference will become invalid as soon as `k` is returned from the function. When items are moved by-value, their address will change, so references are no longer valid.

One potential solution is to use [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```
fn filter<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Rc<RefCell<Keeper>>
    where F: Fn() -> bool + 'static //'
{
    let mut k = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Keeper::new()));
    let k2 = k.clone();
    self.subscribe(move || {
        if f() { k2.borrow_mut().publish() }
    });
    k
}
```

Comment: Perfect understanding of the problem. :) I really feel I start understanding the lifetimes concept better. But do you have any suggestions on how to solve it? I've updated the question.

Comment: @Emanuel not a great one, I used a pretty big hammer, but I've updated.

Comment: Excellent explanation and working solution. I've got lots to think about. I'm marking this question as solved. Thanks!